# date_add incrementing months does not work correctly on last day of the month

Tags: php

I'm developing a php app and for this I use the function `date_add` to get an array of months like this:

```
$months = array();
        $n_6 = date_add(date_create(), date_interval_create_from_date_string('-6 months'));
        $n_5 = date_add(date_create(), date_interval_create_from_date_string('-5 months'));
        $n_4 = date_add(date_create(), date_interval_create_from_date_string('-4 months'));
        $n_3 = date_add(date_create(), date_interval_create_from_date_string('-3 months'));
        $n_2 = date_add(date_create(), date_interval_create_from_date_string('-2 months'));
        $n_1 = date_add(date_create(), date_interval_create_from_date_string('-1 months'));
        $n = date_create();
        $n1 = date_add(date_create(), date_interval_create_from_date_string('+1 months'));
        $n2 = date_add(date_create(), date_interval_create_from_date_string('+2 months'));
        $n3 = date_add(date_create(), date_interval_create_from_date_string('+3 months'));
        $n4 = date_add(date_create(), date_interval_create_from_date_string('+4 months'));
        array_push($months, $n4, $n3, $n2, $n1, $n, $n_1, $n_2, $n_3, $n_4, $n_5, $n_6);
```

The problem is that today is the last day of March and I bellieve because of this I'm getting some things wrong, when i do `var_dump($months)` it displays the following:

```
array(11) { 
    [0]=> object(DateTime)#1026 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2016-07-31 15:45:53.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/Berlin" } 
    [1]=> object(DateTime)#1025 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2016-07-01 15:45:53.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/Berlin" } 
    [2]=> object(DateTime)#1024 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2016-05-31 15:45:53.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/Berlin" } 
    [3]=> object(DateTime)#1023 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2016-05-01 15:45:53.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/Berlin" } 
    [4]=> object(DateTime)#1022 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2016-03-31 15:45:53.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/Berlin" } 
    [5]=> object(DateTime)#1021 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2016-03-02 15:45:53.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/Berlin" } 
    [6]=> object(DateTime)#1020 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2016-01-31 15:45:53.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/Berlin" } 
    [7]=> object(DateTime)#1019 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2015-12-31 15:45:53.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/Berlin" } 
    [8]=> object(DateTime)#1018 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2015-12-01 15:45:53.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/Berlin" } 
    [9]=> object(DateTime)#1017 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2015-10-31 15:45:53.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/Berlin" } 
    [10]=> object(DateTime)#1016 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2015-10-01 15:45:53.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/Berlin" }
}
```

Because I need the just the months, this is a problem. I get some duplicates and some others are skipped, so you know how to fix this? Thanks in advance!!

**EDIT**

The output I want is an array of months, for example if now is March I want the 6 months before and the next 4. so September, October, November and December from 2015; January, February, (March), April, May, June, July.

Comment: What's the desired output, I couldn't understand. Also you could use `$months = range(-6,4);` and do a for to get these objects

Comment: I love how these questions keep appearing within the last day or two...

Comment: @deceze Not as often, but it also happens when the time changes from summer to winter time or vice versa :)

Comment: @Rizier123 It should happen every other month; but I can just picture somebody reporting it, and by the time the report makes its way to a developer the issue has disappeared... :-D D-:

Comment: The output i want is an array of months, for example if now is March I want the 6 months before and the next 4. so September, October, November and December from 2015; January, February, (March), April, May, June, July. And for deceze could you put the link of the question that you say is the same as mine? (:

Comment: Yep it totally has to do with the change, Its just changed this week in Europe, what is the best way to prevent this?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the DST change. Look for the link **at the top of your question.**

Comment: I saw it but how do you do that for more than one month? sorry if I'm being silly but I'm new to php development. (:

Comment: I just saw that tomorrow it will work fine, but do you have any idea of what could be done. maybe its because this year February has more days?